# logic app : use another account to send mail

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

I am searching a way to automate some email reporting

I have build a process with a logic app to do that. The problem is when I want to create an API connection to office 365 with another account than mine (for example email.reporting@xxx.com), I cannot because I am log with my personal account, so it always use my account to create the API connection.

I cannot also log to the portal with this other account because it doesn't have any access. What is the best way to do that?
Is it possible to give the access to the logic app to this other account then I can access to it and change the connection?

Or there is a trick that allow to change api connection directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my test I could use two different account to send mails, cause you don't show how you add account, maybe you could refer to my below steps.

After I set an action to send mail then I add other action to send mail, choose `Change connection`, then choose `Add new`, it will pop up a page you could choose existing account also could `Use another account`.

[image]

Comment: But I guess you add a connection to Office 365 API before do that, right? I have the same issue and the logic app no signed in the Outlook without this API connection.